# Как сделать цикл for in с hasOwnProperty функцией

Tags: javascript

Я хочу сделать функцию, который мы передадим объект и функцию, которая пройдётся по всем элементам массива и сделает `if (object.hasOwnProperty(key))`, но не получается
Возможно в языке уже есть подобный перебор, но я не знаю как он называется

```js
const person = Object.create({
  calculateAge() {
    console.log(this.age);
  }
}, {
  name: {
    value: 'Misha',
    enumerable: true,
    writable: false,
    configurable: false
  },
  birthYear: {
    value: 1993,
    enumerable: true,
    writable: false,
    configurable: false
  },
  age: {
    get() {
      return new Date().getFullYear() - this.birthYear;
    },
    set(value) {
      console.log('Set age', value + ', this age:', this.age);
    }
  }
});

for (let key in person) {
  if (person.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key, person[key], person.age);
  }
} // Как я хочу, чтобы работало

function forInHasOwnProperty(key, object, code) {
  for (let key in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      code();
    }
  }
}

forInHasOwnProperty('key', person, function() {
  console.log('key', person['key'], person.age);;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну функция же должна как-то узнать, что выводить)

Вы пытаетесь найти ключ по СТРОКЕ `"key"` - а её там нет.

```js
const person = Object.create(
  { // __proto__
    bubu: {
      value: 1000,
      enumerable: false,
    },
  },
  { // own properties
    a: { value: 1, enumerable: true },
    b: { value: 2, enumerable: true },
    c: { value: 3, enumerable: true },
    age: { value: 10 }
  }
);

console.log( person.__proto__.bubu === person.bubu ); //* true

forInHasOwnProperty(person, log);

function log(obj, key) {
  console.log(key, obj[key], obj.age);
}

/***/

function forInHasOwnProperty(obj, callback) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      callback(obj, key); // Отдаем аргументы на обработку
    } else {
      console.log("Not own: " + key);
    }
  }
}
```

> Возможно в языке уже есть подобный перебор

[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) / - - / [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) / - - /  [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Все они смотрят только на свойства самого объекта.

```js
const person = Object.create(
  {
    bubu: {
      value: 1000,
      enumerable: false,
    },
  },
  {
    a: { value: 1, enumerable: true },
    b: { value: 2, enumerable: true },
    c: { value: 3, enumerable: true },
    age: { value: 10 }
  }
);

Object.entries(person).forEach(function([key, value]) {//Называется `Деструктуризация`
  console.log(key, value, person.age);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Если посмотреть на исходный цикл, видно что его входным параметром является только объект, свойства которого перебираются. Поэтому в функции нужно убрать параметр `key`.

Теперь, чтобы вывести ключ внутри коллбэка, его необходимо передать в качестве параметра

```
code(key);
```

```js
const person = Object.create({
  calculateAge() {
    console.log(this.age);
  }
}, {
  name: {
    value: 'Misha',
    enumerable: true,
    writable: false,
    configurable: false
  },
  birthYear: {
    value: 1993,
    enumerable: true,
    writable: false,
    configurable: false
  },
  age: {
    get() {
      return new Date().getFullYear() - this.birthYear;
    },
    set(value) {
      console.log('Set age', value + ', this age:', this.age);
    }
  }
});

for (let key in person) {
  if (person.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key, person[key], person.age);
  }
} // Как я хочу, чтобы работало

function forInHasOwnProperty(object, code) {
  for (let key in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      code(key);
    }
  }
}

forInHasOwnProperty(person, function(key) {
  console.log(key, person[key], person.age);
});
```